# Oracle Function To Return List

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to develop a PLSQL function that outputs a list of employee names that I can then run through another script. I can't quite get it right though. I'm fairly new to PLSQL and am primarily used to building functions in Python, so I may be thinking about this the wrong way. At the end of all of this, I'd like to use the output of this within another script I'm writing.

Baseline Script:

```
   SELECT EMPLOYEE FROM (
   SELECT ID, EMPLOYEE, ROLE, STARTDATE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE ORDER BY STARTDATE DESC, ID DESC) RN
    FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT E.EMPLOYEE EMPLOYEE,
    E.ID ID,
    LR.DESCRIPTION ROLE, 
    ROLE_START_DATE STARTDATE
    FROM EMPLOYEES E
    JOIN ROLES R ON E.EMPLOYEE_ID = R.EMPLOYEE_ID
    JOIN LU_ROLES LR ON R.ROLE_ID = LR.ROLE_ID
    WHERE ROLE_START_DATE <= DATE '2017-12-03'))
    WHERE RN = 1
```

My attempt at writing a PLSQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_employees(EMPLOYEE IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS EMPLOYEE_LIST;
    BEGIN
        SELECT EMPLOYEE FROM (
        SELECT ID, EMPLOYEE, ROLE, STARTDATE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE ORDER BY STARTDATE DESC, ID DESC) RN
        FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT E.EMPLOYEE EMPLOYEE,
        E.ID ID,
        LR.DESCRIPTION ROLE, 
        ROLE_START_DATE STARTDATE
        FROM EMPLOYEES E
        JOIN ROLES R ON E.EMPLOYEE_ID = R.EMPLOYEE_ID
        JOIN LU_ROLES LR ON R.ROLE_ID = LR.ROLE_ID
        WHERE ROLE_START_DATE <= DATE '2017-12-03'))
        WHERE RN = 1
    RETURN EMPLOYEE_LIST
    END;
```

I know I'm missing some syntax, I just don't know what and why...I'm reading through the docs at the moment to try to understand this. Any help you all could provide would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: you have missing `;`

Comment: What is the parameter `EMPLOYEE` for? It doesn't seem to be used anywhere. Neither is `EMPLOYEE_LIST` (and its declaration is missing a datatype).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this would it work ?

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_employees(EMPLOYEE IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS EMPLOYEE_LIST VARCHAR2(200);
    BEGIN
        SELECT EMPLOYEE into EMPLOYEE_LIST FROM (
        SELECT ID, EMPLOYEE, ROLE, STARTDATE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE ORDER BY STARTDATE DESC, ID DESC) RN
        FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYEE EMPLOYEE,
        E.ID ID,
        LR.DESCRIPTION ROLE, 
        ROLE_START_DATE STARTDATE
        FROM EMPLOYEES E
        JOIN ROLES R ON E.EMPLOYEE_ID = R.EMPLOYEE_ID
        JOIN LU_ROLES LR ON R.ROLE_ID = LR.ROLE_ID
        WHERE ROLE_START_DATE <= DATE '2017-12-03'))
        WHERE RN = 1;
    RETURN EMPLOYEE_LIST;
    END;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! But I get an error stating `an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement`. Its referring to this: `SELECT EMPLOYEE into EMPLOYEE_LIST FROM (`... Which is odd because there IS an `INTO` within that SELECT statement. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: You should rename function's parameter. Naming it the same as one of columns you select is a bad idea.

Comment: @grigs try to add into in the second select

Answer (score 2):

Without your tables or sample data this has to be a bit of a guess, but a "fixed" version might be something like this:

```
create or replace type short_string_tt as table of varchar2(100)
/

create or replace function get_employees
    ( p_role_date_cutoff roles.role_start_date%type )
    return short_string_tt
as
    l_employee_list short_string_tt;
begin
    select employee bulk collect into l_employee_list
    from   ( select employee
                  , row_number() over(partition by employee order by role_start_date desc, id desc) rn
             from   ( select distinct e.employee, e.id, lr.description, role_start_date
                      from   employees e
                             join roles r
                                  on  r.employee_id = e.id
                             join lu_roles lr
                                  on  lr.role_id = r.role_id
                      where  role_start_date <= p_role_date_cutoff )
           )
    where  rn = 1;

    return l_employee_list;
end;
/
```

If the number of rows returned is likely to be significant then you might look at making it a [pipelined function](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions), as these stream rows back as they are fetched rather than building the entire collection in memory before returning anything.